# A notion of "generalized nerve" of categories enriched over a presheaf

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category, $p : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ a functor, and $\mathsf{P} = \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ the category of presheaves over $\mathcal{C}$ valued in sets. The category $\mathsf{P}$ has a monoidal structure induced by that of the cartesian product in $\mathsf{Set}$, so we can consider the category $\mathsf{Cat}_\mathsf{P}$ of categories enriched over $\mathsf{P}$. I'm interested in constructing a functor $\mathsf{Cat}_{\mathsf{P}} \to \mathsf{P}$ that generalizes the coherent nerve $\mathsf{Cat}_{\mathsf{SSet}} \to \mathsf{SSet}$, namely the nerve of simplicial categories; here $p(a)$, for $a$ an object of $\mathcal{C}$, should play the role of $[n]$.

Let me give a bit of context. I'll be following section 1.2 of Land's *Introduction to $\infty$-categories*. The nerve of an ordinary category is the functor $N : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{SSet}$ given by $N(\mathcal{C})_n := \mathrm{Fun}([n], \mathcal{C})$, where $[n]$ is the usual poset category $0 \to 1 \to \dotsb \to n$. Now, there happens to be a fully faithful functor $c : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Cat}_{\mathsf{SSet}}$ that takes a category $\mathcal{C}$ to the simplicial category $c\mathcal{C}$ with

- the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ as objects, and
- for any two objects $x, y$ a simplicial set $\mathrm{Hom}_{c\mathcal{C}}(x, y)$ whose only non-degenerate simplices are in dimension $0$, where we have ($\mathrm{Hom}_{c\mathcal{C}}(x, y))_0 = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(x, y)$.

We can then extend $N$ to a functor $N' : \mathsf{Cat}_\mathsf{SSet} \to \mathsf{SSet}$ with the property that $N(\mathcal{C}) \cong N'(c\mathcal{C})$ for any small category $\mathcal{C}$. The construction of $N'$ involves that of another functor $\mathfrak{C} : \mathsf{SSet} \to \mathsf{Cat}_\mathsf{SSet}$, its left adjoint, so that we have $N'(\mathcal{C})_n := \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Cat}_\mathsf{SSet}}(\mathfrak{C}(\Delta^n), \mathcal{C})$.

The basic notions (nerve and embedding) are generalizable. We can define $N : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{P}$ by setting $N(\mathcal{D})(a) := \mathrm{Fun}(p(a), \mathcal{D})$. We can also get a fully faithful functor $c : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Cat}_{\mathsf{P}}$ that returns the category $c\mathcal{C}$ with the same objects and whose hom-presheaf $\mathrm{Hom}_{c\mathcal{C}}(x, y)$ is the constant presheaf with value $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(x, y)$. I'm now stuck with defining $N' : \mathsf{Cat}_{\mathsf{P}} \to \mathsf{P}$. Finding an analogue of $\mathfrak{C}$ is tricky because Land's definition exploits the order properties of $[n]$ to form an appropriate poset category that he can then take the nerve of. The arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ that I originally picked is not required to have any special properties, so I don't know how to proceed. All the properties I know I want are that $N' \circ c \cong N$ and that $N'$ is a right-adjoint.

Am I missing some properties of the ordinary nerve that would help define this generalized nerve on presheaf-enriched categories? Also, is this direction worth exploring/has it been explored before? My interest, originally, stemmed not from the nerve construction but rather from its left adjoint, the homotopy category functor. Maybe, by studying this generalized nerve, there's a chance to investigate a notion of "homotopy" that behaves on an (almost) arbitrary presheaf category $\mathsf{P}$ like regular homotopy behaves for simplicial sets.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bourke-Garner’s work in this area (Monads and Theories), or that of Berger-Mellies-Webber (Monads with Arities and their Associated Theories). Part of what you're describing seems to be the idea of density, which Chapter 5 of Kelly covers quite well (Basic Concepts in Enriched Category Theory).

Comment: @BenMacAdam No, I'm not familiar with it, but I'll take a look at your reference. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if those papers directly relate to homotopy, but they do cover generalized nerve constructions.